# Virtuemart lost category bypassing shop.browse

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I can't believe, no one got my problem before.
Using joomla 1.5 and VM 1.1.9.
I'd like to have a personal menù (jquery) linking directly products (is just a portfolio/catalog). But if I don't follow shop.browse page, I lose category ID and I can't go forward and backward to other elements.
Thanks
Tru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A product can be in multiple categories, so you must specify the category_id that you want.  Once VM finds that in the query string, it can navigate that category in the same way that you're expecting.  It works properly from shop_browse because VM includes the first category_id that it finds for the product.

Comment: So, there's no way to bypass shop_browse, maybe linking handly the category?

Comment: Yes, you can bypass shop.browse, just take a close look at what the links from that page contain.  Not *all* of them are necessarily required, but category_id, for example, must be supplied if you want the product navigation to appear (needs a category to navigate).

Comment: Can I continue my delirium? I passed to joomla 2.5.6 and virtuemart 2.0.8c. I bypassed the problem above but... now I can't figure how I can slide products not by ID but follow order or other kind of measure. I noted that URL is built properly with ID "$prev_link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->neighbours ['previous'][0] ['virtuemart_product_id'] . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_category_id);". Is there a way to modify navigation parameters? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid the only navigation is with the category that is specified.

Comment: Right... I'm talking about order. I would like present products in different order... not just using ID product.

Comment: By navigation, I'm referring to the top of each product page: the "next" product and "previous" product.  Are you referring to "ordering" them on the category browse page and/or search results?

Comment: Sorry... I'm talking about navigating from product details. I don't need a page shop or categories view. My personal menu directs to first specific product and then I can slide from product to product.
http://www.jdt-dev.com/moveo/gal.html

Comment: And how do you set shop.browse.php to search simultaneously in two or three categories, like setting a variable with comma or an array ?

Comment: That would take some hacking...seems straightforward enough at first, but there are many decisions along the way are based on "the" category, so not sure how much/little work it would take, even if it were possible.    I've had to build an alternate component to accomplish it, though there may be other more native ways if you study it.